# Accessing folders ouside of root IIS

Tags: c#, windows, iis-7

I need to write files into a folder using c# that is outside of root folder on IIS  7.

I have made the folder and given IIS_IUSRS and the app pool users all rights on the folder but I always get UnauthorizedAccessException when I try to write to it.

Everything I googled says the solution is virtual directory, but I cant have the folder emptied every time I publish the web.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting or its just your machine ?

Comment: Shared hosting.

Comment: In shared hosting they won't allow you to access above you folder, if though you are able to do it in local it will fail in production

Comment: Thats true and thus the question above :)

Comment: you are on a shared hosting and yet you are able give access to folders outside your hosting ? Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to grant file access permissions to the **NETWORK SERVICE** account.

Comment: I also did that. I also tryed to change the application pool identity´s biult in account to Network service.